# The current path, account/active/Z1s6IYaohOJWeRV4, didn't match any of these

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkYPb.png)

urls.py:

```
path('active/(?P<active_code>.*)/$', ActiveUserView.as_view(), name='active_user'),
```

views.py:

```
class ActiveUserView(View):
    def get(self,request,active_code):
        users = UserProfile.objects.filter(code=active_code)       
        if users:          
            users.is_active = True
            users.save()  
        else:
            users.delete()       
            return HttpResponse('Fail！Register Again!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("account:user_login"))
```

Comment: you should simply add a slash at the end of your url to fix it. `account/active/Z1s6IYaohOJWeRV4/`

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but it didn't seem to solve the problem